# Are "grouping types" a good idea when designing GraphQL APIs?

Tags: api-design, graphql, graphql-js

When creating types in GraphQL, the list of fields on a type can become quite long after a while. One way of keeping the number of fields down would be to put some relevant subset of the fields in to one "grouping" type, so instead of `user { last_name, first_name, height, weight, friends, favorite_clubs }` one would have `user { identification, friends, favorite_clubs }` where the schema for `identification` is of course `{ last_name, first_name, height, weight }`.

However, I'm not convinced that doing this is a good idea. The advantage is that the `user` type is more readable, but the things that worry me are:

- You are creating a new `GraphQLObjectType` just for the sake of organisation, it's not a new node in my mental model of the graph...
- The `root` parameter of the `identification` resolver would still be the user object, which feels like I'm doing something wrong...

Is this a good way of organising your API, or are my worries correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it all comes down to what you prefer, there is no real answer to this question.

I would personally simply list all the individual fields. :)
Doesn't mean the other way is wrong.

Anyways, **don't overthink it**.